# Pouchdb - tweaking live replication

Tags: replication, live, pouchdb

Using live replication, there is a GET request every 25 secs aprox asking for changes.

is there a way to set this interval to a larger interval?

This could be useful considering some hosting services charge per transaction and they consider options as heavy (cloudant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's odd; replication should be done using long-polling, i.e. one long request.

Unless there are documents to replicate from the server to the client, in which case, yeah, there will be a GET for each one.

Whatever may be causing this, you can use [pouchdb-dump](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-dump-cli) and [pouchdb-load](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-load) to do initial replication in a single request.

Comment: Already using dump and load.
tested with the latest dump 

var self.remoteserver = "http://asdfsd@vpease.cloudant.com/super"
return self.db.load('data/' + dumpFile,
                        { proxy: self.remoteserver, ajax:{cache:true}});

this is what i am doing, considering proxy to considering checkpoints. 

the last thing i will try is to generate dump with the same url as the final server.

Comment: also this is the command to start the replication:   var sync = self.db.replicate.from(
                self.remoteserver,
                {live:true, retry:true})